# How to delete element from array in firebase starts with string

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have firebase database with something like that
[image]

and I want to delete elements starting with "12-07-20210EN5443..."
i have no idea how to do that in firebase, and i spend hours on searching.
i tried with that

```
await db.collection('Hotels')
    .doc(hotelName)
    .update({
        [date]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(fieldName+"%")
    })
```

Comment: Where are you getting `fieldName`? Is it a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single operation that allows you to delete items from an array based on a prefix. The `arrayRemove` operation looks for an exact, complete match.

So you will need to do this in multiple steps:

1. Read the matching documents.
2. Modify their array in your application code.
3. Write back the modified array.